# ArrayList becomes null

Tags: android, arraylist

I have written a service and get xml from web server and after that i put it in my ArrayList. The problem i am facing is that i have bind my service to AlarmManager and it executes it after every one minute, and the arraylist gets null every time the service is called. I want to retain is previous values but unable to find any solution.

Comment: we cannot help you ... ours magic orbs seems not working now ... in other words u didn't supply enough information to answer your question... wait magic orb is working ... it tells me: ArrayList is local var in your Service ... every minute AlarmManager starts new Service, so ArrayList is null ...

Comment: We would need to see your code in order to spot any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The somewhat evil way is create your `ArrayList` as a class variable on your service:

```
private static ArrayList myList;
```

This should allow the value of `myList` to stick around across instantiations of your service.

Depending on what your code is doing it will be better to read data from the calling `Intent` or to persist intermediate data in the [service lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle) methods.

Comment: I have already tried it by making it static. I cannot post my code over here as it quite big though i can send you the whole package if anyone is willing to see my buggy code :)....

Comment: I was doing a dumbest thing......i was clearing adapter explicitly and blaming my ListArray :(....